# Storing to memory - BCD or binary?

Tags: memory, memory-management, binary, bcd

If an X86_64 machine save a integer `56` will that be stored in the memory cells as binary `00111000` or `BCD` `01010110`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost always stored in pure binary (unsigned or 2's complement).  Your program would have to do something special to store it in BCD, and very few programs have any reason to do that.